# Input intellisense on functions?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

How do i input intellisense info on my functions? With C# on VS2010 i just used "///" in front of the function and it made a template automatically. On C++ VS2012 i cant get anything to work.

Comment: You mean the documentation?, you can use an extension like GhostDoc, then you just assign a shortcut like (ctr + shift + d), and it will automaticly document the function with the template, it will also try to guess what the function does based on its name.

Comment: @AngelCastillo you should post this as an answer, it's likely this is exactly what the OP is looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about the documentation of the funcion, you can use an extension like GhostDoc.

Link:
http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx

You can assign a shortcut (by default is ctr + shift + d), and it will automaticly document the function with the template, it will also try to guess what the function does based on its name.

This is an example of ghost doc:

```
/// <summary>
/// Initialize a complex number with a real and imaginary part.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="real">The real.</param>
/// <param name="imaginary">The imaginary.</param>
public Complex(double real, double imaginary)
{
    this.real = real;
    this.imaginary = imaginary;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. I thought that was a function of VS itself since it was build in the C# 2010 version. I will certainly extend VS2012 with it! Thank you.

Comment: Darn, i was too soon with accepting this as answer. Ghostdoc does not work with the express edition of VS.
Is there something like this that can be use with the express edition?

Comment: It seems that addins are not supported by express editions of Visual Studio :(, you can try to mimic it with code snippets and create a short cut for it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Check out XMLDoc comments functionality in Visual Studio:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177226(v=vs.100).aspx